# devc++ input from file does not work

Tags: c++, dev-c++

I'm trying to redirect a  .txt content to .exe

program.exe < file.txt

and contents of file.txt are

```
35345345345
34543534562
23435635432
35683045342
69849593458
95238942394
28934928341
```

but the first index in array is the file path and the file contents is not displayed.

```
int main(int argc, char *args[])
   {
    for(int c = 0; c<argc; c++){
            cout << "Param " << c << ": " << args[c] << "\n";
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Desired output:

```
Param0: 35345345345
Param1: 34543534562
Param2: 23435635432
Param3: 35683045342
Param4: 69849593458
Param5: 95238942394
Param6: 28934928341
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the source of that program, can you add it to the question?

Comment: edited, src included.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `myapp < file.txt` syntax passes to `stdin` (or `cin` if you prefer), not the arguments.

Comment: hmmm. I see. Is it possible to change the behavior?

Comment: What shell are you using? See medgno's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have misunderstood what `argc` and `argv` are for. They contain the command line arguments to your program. If, for example, you ran:

```
program.exe something 123
```

The null terminated strings pointed to by `argv` will be `program.exe`, `something`, and `123`.

You are attempting to redirect the contents of a file to `program.exe` using `< file.txt`. This is *not* a command line argument. It simply redirects the contents of the file to the standard input of your program. To get those contents you will need to extract from `std::cin`.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "but the first index in array is the file path and the file contents is not displayed." it sounds like you're trying to read input from argv and argc.  The angle bracket shell operator does not work that way.  Instead, stdin (what cin and several C functions read from) has the contents of that file.  So, to read from the file in the case above, you'd use cin.

If you instead *really* wanted to have a file automatically inserted into the argument list, I can't help you with the windows shell.  However, if you have the option of using `bash`, the following will work:

```
program.exe `cat file.txt`
```

The backtick operator expands into the result of the command contained within, and so the contents are then passed as arguments to program.exe (again, under the `bash` shell and not the windows shell)

Comment: thanks. i'm using windows atm. btw that was useful, as i use linux most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

This code does what i was expecting to do with the other one. Thanks everybody who helped.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
string line;
while (getline(cin, line))
    cout << "line: " << line << '\n';
}
```